# do a groupby and check a column for values greater than X, keep that data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to figure out how to do a group by and keep data only if value col is greater equal than 5

I have a data set shown below:

| groups | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

I should get back:

| groups | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |

Comment: why do you need groupby. seems like a simple boolean mask would work

Comment: @enke. I think the OP wants to keep the group if ALL values are greater than or equal to 5.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
out = df[df.groupby('groups')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.ge(5).all())]
print(out)

# Output
   groups  value
0       1      5
1       1     10
```